# What does the hexdump of the first 16 bytes of /dev/random mean?

Tags: random-number-generator

What does the hex dump of the first 16 bytes of /dev/random mean?

When I run `head -c 16 /dev/random` I get the following results:

0000000 fd43 2676 f87d 8f78 00c9 3119 f697 100c

0000010

What do these mean?

---

I should have been more specific, what does 0000010 mean because that values is the same no matter how many times I run the command.

Comment: They mean nothing. That's the point.

Answer (score 5):

They mean absolutely nothing, they are **random** numbers.

Edit: The `0000000` and `000010` are byte indexes of the hex dump. It starts at byte `0x00` and ends at byte `0x0f`. `hexdump` displays another line for the next byte.

```
head -c 17 /dev/random | hexdump
```

will display something like this:

```
0000000 11db e37a 80f1 1b74 733b 391b 3f0a f2f6
0000010 006e
0000011
```

Comment: Maybe it could be analyzed using SETI@home client? :)

Comment: @EsaJokinen: This would have approximately the same chance of success :)

Comment: OK, this makes more sense. See my edit.